# Plotting Lowess smoothing curve in SigmaPlot

Tags: sigmaplot

I am trying to plot a Lowess smoothing curve in Sigmaplot.

I have plotted the data points in an X-Y scatterplot, and I have also run code that gave me my Lowess function (column of values), however I do not know how to plot the curve on the graph (I'm new to Sigmaplot). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider posting what you have tried already

Comment: I have tried using the "smooth data" function from the analysis tab, smoothing 2-D data. When prompted, I select the Y only option to plot only Y values (my Lowess smoothed values). This just creates another plot entirely, rather than adding the curve to my already existing X-Y scatter plot. It worked for one graph for some reason but not the others...